# PHP - What is wrong with my IF

Tags: php

What im trying to do is:
IF Posts are more than 3 do this code {...} else echo 'Posts are less than 3'.
The problem is that even when posts are 2 or 1 the code will still execute and the "else echo 'Posts are less than 3'" wont work.

```
$type = get_field(field_553005f456c6);

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'meta_key'=> 'custom-ca',
    'meta_value'=> $type,
    'numberposts'   => -1,
));


if($posts > 3 ) {
   echo '<a href="#" id="prev2">Prev</a><div class="pics" id="s2" style="position: relative;">';
 $i = 0; foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );
if ($i == '0') {echo '<ul class="dfggr">';} else {}
   echo '<li class="thecust"><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">'; the_title(); echo '</a></li>';
if ($i == '1') {echo '</ul>'; $i++;} else {$i++;}
if ($i == '2') {$i = '0';} else {}
    endforeach;
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<a href="#" id="next2">Next</a>';
} else {echo '<h1>Posts are less than 3</h1>';}
     wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: i think you need to use $posts.count()

Comment: These `if` statements should be replaced with `else if`.

Comment: Can you please show us the `get_posts` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $posts  variable is an array.

```
if(count($posts) > 3 ) {
       echo '<a href="#" id="prev2">Prev</a><div class="pics" id="s2" style="position: relative;">';
     $i = 0; foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );
    if ($i == '0') {echo '<ul class="dfggr">';} else {}
       echo '<li class="thecust"><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">'; the_title(); echo '</a></li>';
    if ($i == '1') {echo '</ul>'; $i++;} else {$i++;}
    if ($i == '2') {$i = '0';} else {}
        endforeach;
       echo '</div>';
       echo '<a href="#" id="next2">Next</a>';
    } else {echo '<h1>Posts are less than 3</h1>';}
         wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks man it works, i just had to change this from your code    if(count($posts) > 3 )

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as correct @Jordan. It is happening to me all day long))

Comment: This is not even valid php ! `$posts.count()` What should that be?

Comment: Mixed with js. Edited now